# Remove four last digits from string – Convert Zip+4 to Zip code

Tags: python, pandas

The following piece of code...

```
data = np.array([['','state','zip_code','collection_status'],
                ['42394','CA','92637-2854', 'NaN'],
                ['58955','IL','60654', 'NaN'],
                ['108365','MI','48021-1319', 'NaN'],
                ['109116','MI','48228', 'NaN'],
                ['110833','IL','60008-4227', 'NaN']])

print(pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:]))
```

... gives the following data frame:

```
         state            zip_code    collection_status
42394       CA          92637-2854                  NaN
58955       IL               60654                  NaN
108365      MI          48021-1319                  NaN
109116      MI               48228                  NaN
110833      IL          60008-4227                  NaN
```

The goal is to homogenise the "zip_code" column into a 5-digits format–i.e. I want to remove the last four last digits from zip_code when that particular data point has 9 digits instead of 5. BTW, zip_code's type is "object" type.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) only, thanks [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776115/remove-four-last-digits-from-string-convert-zip4-to-zip-code/44776170#comment76532857_44776170):

```
df['collection_status'] = df['zip_code'].str[:5]
print (df)
       state    zip_code collection_status
42394     CA  92637-2854             92637
58955     IL       60654             60654
108365    MI  48021-1319             48021
109116    MI       48228             48228
110833    IL  60008-4227             60008
```

If need add conditions use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['collection_status'] = df['zip_code'].where(df['zip_code'].str.len() == 5, 
                                               df['zip_code'].str[:5])
print (df)
       state    zip_code collection_status
42394     CA  92637-2854             92637
58955     IL       60654             60654
108365    MI  48021-1319             48021
109116    MI       48228             48228
110833    IL  60008-4227             60008
```

---

```
df['collection_status'] = np.where(df['zip_code'].str.len() == 5, 
                                   df['zip_code'],
                                   df['zip_code'].str[:5])
print (df)
       state    zip_code collection_status
42394     CA  92637-2854             92637
58955     IL       60654             60654
108365    MI  48021-1319             48021
109116    MI       48228             48228
110833    IL  60008-4227             60008
```

Comment: Wondering, if `df.zip_code.str[:5]` is enough to work, without the need for where checks?